# Idiomatic way of modifying an immutable collection

Tags: scala

I'm interested in understanding the pattern of modifying an immutable collection in the most effective way.

Suppose for example I want to define the following class (an actual implementation may overload the operators, but this is just for illustration). Is this the best way (with respect to performance / safety)?

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
class Example[A,B] {
  var col = new HashMap[A, B]()
  def add(k: A, v: B): Unit = col =  col +  (k -> v)
  def remove(k: A): Unit = col = col - k  
}
```

would this approach be possible as well, in some way I'm missing?

```
class Example[A,B] extends HashMap[A,B] {
  def add(k: A, v: B): Unit = ???
  def remove(k: A): Unit = ???
}
```

Comment: I know I may sound obvious, but the most efficient way is not use immutable collection at all: in this particular case you would be better off with private val that utilizes mutable map

Comment: om-nom-nom is correct. Once you have used a `var`, you have already introduced immutability. You don't gain clarity by making the type of the `var` be an immutable collection.

Comment: @om-nom-nom  I understand, and the var in that case was necessary to make that approach work. Not claiming it's the best way of doing it. The point of the question was to ask the experts for better ways of doing it, in an idiomatic way.

Answer (score 2):

The comments above are correct. The idea of immutable data structures exists and there are ways to do it, however, it seems that you may just want to stick with a mutable structure since you have a `var` anyway.

Check out chapter 17 of the free online pdf of Programming In Scala [here](http://www.lirmm.fr/~ducour/Doc-objets/scalabook.pdf) where Odersky discusses the designing and building of an Immutable queue.

The gist of it is that you never actually modify the structure that you're trying to change, you just take it in, look at it, and then build a new one based on the old one and whatever it is you're trying to do.

It's the same idea behind the fact that with lists:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
1 :: list
println(list)
```

Will print out `List(1,2,3)` as opposed to `List(1,1,2,3)`

While:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
val list1 = 1 :: list
println(list1)
```

is what prints `List(1,1,2,3)`

Here's a nice slide deck that discusses some popular data structures and their functional counterparts. [Functional Data Structures](http://www.slideshare.net/vkostyukov/purely-functional-data-structures-in-scala-26175521)

Comment: Thanks. The var was just a way to get that particular approach to work, I'd get rid of it if I could.

If I move my code to a mutable collection, I'd have to mix in a concurrent thread to make it thread safe. Which, performance-wise, is probably okay if I have mostly reads, correct? Given a small collection of 100-200 items with occasional (10-20 per minute) updates, which is best to use? 

Anyway, my question was mostly academic, to understand Scala better. Thanks for the PDF link, I will do some reading.

Comment: @WillIAm in case your code is concurrent you may have troubles with var despite the fact that data structure will be immutable by itself

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to make immutable data structures mutable. There are situations where you need to think about performance to be sure, but given that Scala has persistent data structures I'd focus on the use case and not the performance model.

```
val a = Map("key1" -> "some value")
val b = a + ("key2" -> "some other value")
```

Now `b` contains both entries.

If you actually need the mutable structures for your case, just use the `mutable.Map`.

Comment: Thanks. The use case is small collectons (up to 200 items), and I need very fast read access. Writes are not very common, and may happen once every 5 seconds or so... I need to support the GetOrElseAdd() pattern in  a thread safe way.